# cache method in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching

I have a questions about cache method in rails. Please take a look at the below code. It's about fragment caching.

```
<% cache text_post do %>
  <% sleep 1 %>
  -- snip --
<% end %>
```

I put a sleep method in the code to see the effect of rails cache method. After this cache, rails doesn't execute the sleep method anymore thus improving performance. But I don't understand why the sleep method doesn't get executed after caching. As far as I see the sleep method isn't view data but a method. I think it should be executed no matter it's cached or not.

Thank you for help in advance.

Answer (score 1):

The execution of the cached block depends on the cached key. When its called first time it produces a key, value pair and stores on your underlying caching storage. Here key is `text_post` and the value is the output of the `block`. So unless your cache expires or your key gets removed, the cached block will remain untouched. If the `text_post` is an activerecord object, if you save the object that cache will be expired and corresponding block will be executed again.

Comment: So what you mean is that after caching, even a method doesn't get executed because it will have been stored for use?

Comment: method is ambiguous here, you can say the cache block wont be executed until the cache key expires/removed